# Filter questions list by question age or activity

Tags: feature-request, custom-filters

Every day, there are a lot of new questions asked, and I'm not always present to browse the good ones. Sorting by *newest* and just going through all the questions I've missed takes too long. What I want to do is sort by *most votes*, but filter the questions list to only include questions from the last X amount of time.

Can we get a filter that allows filtering by question age or activity?

Comment: I guess filtering by vote count also works for my specific case, but that would be a separate feature-request

Comment: Can't you use the Search functionality for that? E.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+created%3A2019

Comment: @Glorfindel I never realized it, and tbh I almost never use search, because it sucks. It always sorts by "Relevant" first even after only changing my search criteria, the "advanced search" features are not clear (e.g. this `created:` is not listed in the _advanced search_ menu) and is clunky to navigate, and every time I want to do the search I have to go through the process again (remember the right filter, oh wait I need to say `is:q`, oh now I have to re-sort, etc).